# Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I am getting this error.

> Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher

And I update the version into 2.1.3 that is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And I get this error:

> TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

I don't know how to solve this issue. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live is deprecated from 1.7 and removed from 1.9
Just use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

```
$( "[selector]").on("events" [, selector ] [, data ], function() {
   ....
});
```

Comment: thanks man that helps.

Comment: Please thank me by clicking the top arrow on the left to my answer

Comment: I am new in this and I have only 13 reputation score so i cant use top arrow right now unless i have 15 reputation score. That's kind of awkward moment for me.

Comment: you can use `bind` too.

Answer (score 1):

Replace in your code `.live()` by `.on()` :

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+


$( "a.offsite" ).live( "click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.3+
});
$( document ).delegate( "a.offsite", "click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.4.3+
});
$( document ).on( "click", "a.offsite", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" );  // jQuery 1.7+
});
```

Source : http://api.jquery.com/live/

You can try to update Bootstrap to the lastest version too.

Comment: Thanks. it solve my problem as well.